# How can I avoid the clipboard message box when copying large amounts of data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I have a macro that is copying 4 sheets from one workbook to a new workbook and saving it down with another name.

Unfortunately the message box asking me whether I would *like to make this large amount of data available for other applications* is causing this automated job to become slightly manual.

Any tips on how to avoid the clipboard message box, or just have it automatically answer No, would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would modify the macro. Turn off alerts when the macro starts and turn them back on when the macro is done.  i.e.  `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Answer (score 9):

The problem with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is that it may hide an alert you need to see.

Use `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the paste, which removes the link to the large range from the clipboard.

Comment: I have this as an xlam addin that runs on the before close event

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jon Peltier, "The problem with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is that it may hide an alert you need to see."
Plus you have to remember to set `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after you're done, so that's 3 lines of code for each paste
AND if your program interrupts BEFORE `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` you'll have unknowingly turned off alerts until you quit Excel.

I tested his suggestion `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the paste, it works fine.  Here is an example in `someSpreadsheet.xls`:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="someDirectory\someFile.txt", _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, _
    Tab:=True
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("someSpreadsheet.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Windows("someFile.txt").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this MS document regarding this.  It looks like you can use a few different programatic solutions in your macro to resolve this.  It just depends on what exactly you are copying to clipboard.[KB # 287392](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287392)

Here's the relevant part:

> Method 2: Exit from CutCopyMode
> If you are using Visual Basic for Applications macro to cut or copy cells, insert the following line immediately before the line that closes the workbook
>
> `workbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False`
>
> where "workbook" is your workbook object.
>
> NOTE: By setting CutCopyMode to True or False, Excel may cancel Cut or Copy mode.
>
> Method 3: Save the Workbook
> If you are using Visual Basic for Applications macro to cut or copy cells, insert the following line immediately before the line that closes the workbook
>
> `workbook.Save`
>
> where "workbook" is your workbook object. When you save a workbook, Excel is no longer in Cut or Copy mode.

Comment: The article was very useful. Thanks very much.

Comment: Link only answer :(