# Turn off (or increase size threshold) for clipboard warning in MS-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, clipboard, microsoft-excel-2011

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/382715/how-can-i-avoid-the-clipboard-message-box-when-copying-large-amounts-of-data-in) asks how to *programmatically* turn off the "there is a large amount of information in the clipboard" warning" that MS-Excel pops up whenever you try to close an Excel file and the clipboard has more than a few cells copied into it.

Is there a *non-programmatic* way to do this? For example, is there some obscure setting that can be changed, or some size threshold that can be increased in order to turn off the warning message? I'd like to make the warning go away permanently, if possible.

If there's no way to change a setting, is there a way to set a macro or VBA script to automatically run at program startup that will turn off the message (preferably without turning off other warning messages, as even Excel has *some* warning messages that are useful)? I have only minimal knowledge of Excel macros or VBA, but I'd be happy to use this as an opportunity to learn more about them.

I'm running Excel for Mac 2011, version 14.2.3 on a Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard. If someone has an answer that works on Windows, please don't hesitate to post it and I will hopefully be able to adapt it to work in OSX.

Comment: I'm short of time to give an answer so I'll just leave a comment for now. Try copying a small amount of data to the clipboard programmatically prior to exiting the spreadsheet. In the VBE, open `ThisWorksheet` and add a sub: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` - do the copy there.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows machine, [increasing the Virtual Memory can increase the size of the Clipboard.](http://www.ehow.com/how_8187636_increase-size-office-clipbook.html#ixzz20skav8s1)